# Russian equivalent of the idiomatic expression “It's all very well doing …”

Tags: выражения

> Делать что-то – **дело хорошее, но** бывает, что ...

To express the idea of "it's all very well doing A, but sometimes it's best to do B", I wonder if the phrasing above sounds idiomatic enough.

In English, we commonly say something like:

> It's **all very well** doing A, but shouldn't we do B first?
>
> {or}: It's **all well and good/dandy** to do ..., but ...

How do Russian speakers commonly express this idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rendering is OK.

I'd only take issue with closely placed cognates `делать ... дело хорошее`. In Russian stacking up cognates is considered poor style.

Maybe a more idiomatic example could look like

> Смотреть фильмы - это/оно конечно хорошо/чудесно/замечательно, но может (быть) сначала нужно/стоит сделать уроки?

The phrase `дело хорошее` to my taste sounds better next to a lone noun (noun phrase) or an infinitive

> Футбол - дело хорошее, но...
>   Жениться - дело хорошее, но...

Comment: By "OK", do you mean that my phrasing is understandable but not how native speakers usually phrase the idea?

Comment: yes pretty much, or depending on the circumstances

Comment: Then, what about if you have just one word, a verb infinitive, in front of the phrase "– дело хорошее": "{infinitive (1 word)} – дело хорошее, но ..."?

Comment: yes, that would be better in my opinion, i've updated the answer

Comment: Interesting. So does the construction "Жениться - дело хорошее, но..." sound **idiomatic** enough?

Comment: i'd say it does

Comment: Notice that you changed the 2nd part of her rendering though. "Делать что-то – дело хорошее, но **бывает, что**" That is correct change, her original attempt corresponds to English "It's all very well doing A, but **sometimes we should** do B first". While your corrected translation convey "..., but shouldn't we **now** do B first?". Correct fix, just you did not mention it in the answer :-)

Comment: @Alone-zee better be "Женитьба - дело хорошее,...". Notice: "дело" is noun so more idiomatic would be to match it with another noun. If the verb is needed i'd more likely say "Жениться - это хорошо" ( or "... это, конечно, хорошо" or with the least change "Жениться - это дело хорошее"). Notice, your variant is already good, more so, in oral casual speech "это" often reduced to shortened "э" and "т" with "o" sound replaced by short pause, like `'этъ`, and also the whole "это" word can be dropped with a small pause put instead. Those are actually very small nuances

Comment: and I repeat - your variant is already quite good, especially in oral speech. My extended variants are a little bit more idiomatic though. Also, "Жениться - оно дело хорошее" and ""Женитьба - оно дело хорошее" can go as well

Comment: Hi. I'm wondering if "Жениться - **дело хорошее, но ...**" can be paraphrased with the structure "**так-то оно так, а/но/да ...**"?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens hi, this phrase of qualified assent is meant to be said in a dialogue situation by the interlocutor who agrees with a statement and then expresses a reservation, therefore within itself it can't contain the actual positive statement